# Chart Js showing the old data and shakes on mouse hover

Tags: javascript

I am making a map application that shows datas from different countries when i click on it. I have an info panel with a chart that shows the data. But after the first click, the old data somehow not updates and when i come over the chart hover it shakes and sometimes shows the old datas.

My code is :

```js
chart = new APP_JS.Chart(canvas, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        labels: ["GERB", "BSP", "VatBir", "HÖH", "Volya", "DOST"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# Oy Sayısı',

            data: [sum_p11, sum_p10, sum_p17, sum_p9, sum_p6, sum_p13],
            backgroundColor: [
                '#ff00bf',
                '#0000ff',
                '#1f77b4',
                '#ffff00',
                '#00ff00',
                '#ff8000'
            ]
        }]
    },
    options: {
        rotation: -Math.PI,
        legend: {
            display: false
        }
    }
})
```

I did the following but it is not working

```js
if (chart != undefined) {
          console.log("Chart is Undefined");
          chart.data.labels.pop();
          chart.data.datasets.forEach(dataset => {
            dataset.data.pop();
          });
          chart.destroy();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a function inside chartJS which is updating the chart

```
chart.update();
```

here is the reference to the [api](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html), but im not sure if this is what your looking for